# How to change windows service logon account using cmd

Tags: windows, cmd, windows-services

[Service Account from GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wytTJ.png)

Need to change windows service logon account but from command line not using GUI.
For example change from: NT Service\MSSQLSERVER to NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
sc.exe config "MSSQLServer" obj= "DOMAIN\USERNAME" password= "PASSWORD" type= own
```

- Where `DOMAIN\USERNAME` Is the username and `PASSWORD` is the password
- Some white spaces are very crucial, don't remove

Comment: Thanks solved!

Change logon account
C:\Users\sqladmin>sc.exe config "MSSQLSERVER" obj= ".\sqluser" password= "xx" type= own
[SC] ChangeServiceConfig SUCCESS

Rollback
C:\Users\sqladmin>sc.exe config "MSSQLSERVER" obj= "NT Service\MSSQLSERVER" password= ""
[SC] ChangeServiceConfig SUCCESS

Comment: It did not work right away, the user I selected did not have the rights to "log on as a service" 
Local Computer Policy\Computer Configuration\Windows Settings\ Security Settings\Local Policies\User Rights Assignment\Log on as a Service
[link](https://morgantechspace.com/2013/11/Set-or-Grant-Logon-As-A-Service-right-to-User.html)